# Flagging low quality answers

Tags: discussion

Imagining that someone post as an answer the following:

```
Can you provide code?
```

I should flagged right?!

Then, bye the time that someone review my flag, the user edit the answer, and endup providing a decent answer.

The moderator see the "new" answer, and decline the flag, should it be accepted? Since, at the time you flagged the answer was low quality.

Comment: Flag, downvote and comment. A mod will see the comment even if the OP edited during the grace period (meaning there is no revision).

Comment: Fair enough, but should not the flag be accepted was helpful. And the answer leave it "alone"?

Comment: It happens, don't worry about it and move on.

Comment: If a mod can't see any evidence for the flag, should they accept it as helpful?

Comment: I am not worry, it makes no different to me really (I had already more than +500). I was just making an observation.

Comment: @Oded Nop. Maybe I did not express my self well. I was wondering if this in a common behavior, Or it was just something pontual.

Comment: As @dreamcrash said - it happens. Nothing to worry about. Rare enough and harmless enough.

Comment: In another words, if you flag some answer and in the meantime this answer is improved, you will get decline instead of helpful? I am just trying to understand how the system operates.

Comment: @Oded, okey, so should I delete this question?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/indicate-that-a-post-has-been-edited-since-being-flagged

Comment: @dreamcrash, definitely don't delete this question. It was a legitimate question. I bet it's a dupe, but in that case it will be closed as a dupe, not deleted.

Comment: @BenLee Thanks, I will not delete it.